# Como posso reaproveitar um HandleChange?

Tags: javascript, react

tenho esse código aqui o qual muda a cor da box de acordo com o `range` do input, porém ao invés de fazer 3 `handlechange` gostariade fazer um só,como faço isso? Até então meu código está assim:

```
 let [color, setColor] = useState({
    red: 0,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0
  });
  
  let handleChange = (e, cor) => {
    let value = e.target.value
    setColor(
       color[cor] = {...color, [cor]:value }      
      
      )
  };


  return (
    <div className="selector">
      <h1>RGB COLOR CHANGER</h1>
      <div className="box" style={{ backgroundColor: `rgb(${color.red}, ${color.green}, ${color.blue})`}} />
      <h1>Selecione sua cor abaixo:</h1>
      R{" "}
      <input
        type="range"
        name="red"
        id="red"
        min="0"
        max="255"
        value={color.red}
        onChange={()=> handleChange(color.red)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problemas encontrados**

Anteriormente a sua function `handleChange` esperava receber no primeiro parametro o `event` do `onChange` e você não estava passando o mesmo para a function supracitada.

O seu estado `color` é um objeto que contém propriedades (red, green e blue) com números atribuídos (por default todos são 0), na sua function `handleChange` você usa o segundo parâmetro para definir dinamicamente o valor do atributo do seu objeto, portando você deveria informar as cores disponíveis *(red, green ou blue)*.
Supondo que você estivesse passando o `event` no primeiro parâmetro no `onChange`, você estaria passando no segundo parâmetro valores numéricos e isso ocasionaria em problemas no seu funcionamento.

**Novo código**

Eu fiz algumas modificações no seu código para que funcionasse da maneira desejada.

`availableColors` contém as cores disponíveis (red, green e blue) com base nas propriedades do seu estado colors;

`handleChangeColorRange` é um [currying](https://rodrigorgs.github.io/aulas/mata56/aula14-currying) ;

Iteramos a variável `availableColors` para renderizar os inputs e passar os dados de acordo com a cor disponível.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ChangeColors = () => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState({
    red: 0,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0
  });

  const availableColors = Object.keys(colors);
  
  function handleChangeColorRange(color) {
    return event => {
      const { value } = event.target;

      setColors({ ...colors, [color]: value });
    };
  }

  return (
    <div className="selector">
      <h1>Selecione sua cor abaixo:</h1>
      <div
        className="box"
        style={{
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: `rgb(${colors.red}, ${colors.green}, ${colors.blue})`
        }}
      />
      {availableColors.map(color => (
        <input
          key={color}
          type="range"
          name={color}
          id={color}
          min="0"
          max="255"
          value={colors[color]}
          onChange={handleChangeColorRange(color)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!